# EntityMalformedException Error in profile2 module

Tags: users

I have installed profile2 module in my site.

After a user is registered, While opening his/her profile page.

The site throws error page like this.
[image]

In status report it shows the following error.

```
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type profile2. 
in entity_extract_ids() (line 7844 of /var/www/html/drupal/includes/common.inc).
```

But after i edit the user and saved it, without any alteration its working fine.

Any fix for this ?

Comment: A dirty fix for this could be [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). Save the user after registration again.

Comment: Have you checked https://www.drupal.org/node/1283996